# Update OrientDB EmbeddedMap Value via SQL

Tags: orientdb

Two related issues:

1) I can set (i.e. completely replace the content of an EmbeddedMap field) with this statement:

```
update #14:1 set Options = {"555":{"Action":"Test555","Enabled":false},"444":{"Action":"Test444","Enabled":false}}
```

But I can add or update a value, for example:

```
update #14:1 add Options = {"222":{"Action":"Test222","Enabled":false},"333":{"Action":"Test333","Enabled":false}}
```

2) I can't seem to figure out a syntax for setting the EmbeddedMap field along with the other fields in the record while creating it.

I've searched high and low for examples of these, and experimented with every variant I could think of, but haven't had any luck on either front. Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
update #14:1 put Options = '222', {"Action":"Test222","Enabled":false}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

I used 2.2.0GA

I used these commands:

```
create class MyClass extends V
insert into MyClass(name) values("test")
update #21:0 set Options = {"555":{"Action":"Test555","Enabled":false},"444":{"Action":"Test444","Enabled":false}}
update #21:0 put Options = '222', {"Action":"Test222","Enabled":false}
select from MyClass
```

[image]

**EDIT 2**

```
create property MyClass4.Options EmbeddedMap V
insert into MyClass4(name) values("test4")
update #34:0 set Options = {"555":{"@type":"d", "@class":"V","Action":"Test555","Enabled":false},"444":{"@type":"d", "@class":"V","Action":"Test444","Enabled":false}}
update #34:0 put Options = '222', {"@type":"d", "@class":"v","Action":"Test222","Enabled":false}
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried it, but get this error: `com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OValidationException: The field 'VMenu.Options' has been declared as EMBEDDEDMAP but an incompatible type is used. Value: {Action=Test222, Enabled=false}`. Also, how does this syntax support adding more than one embedded record at a time?

Comment: Which version of OrientDb are you using ? I'm using 2.1.17

Comment: By the way, I've also tried that same syntax with `@Type` and `@Class` properties, as well as every other syntax version I could think of--all produce errors of one kind or another.

Comment: @eric I'm using 2.2.0GA and it works. I have edited my answer

Comment: OK. I see the difference. My schema defines the Options property as an EMBEDDEDMAP, whereas your Options property is a non-typed property. I just tried using your syntax to add and modify "extOptions" (an undefined property in my schema) and it works, but the data appears to be stored as non-typed data).

Comment: If I use "create property MyClass.Options EmbeddedMap" I get {"444":{"@type":"d","@version":0,"Action":"Test444","Enabled":false},"555":{"@type":"d","@version":0,"Action":"Test555","Enabled":false}}

Comment: If I use "create property MyClass.Options EmbeddedMap V" I get your error

Comment: Interesting. So it works with a generic/non-classed EMBEDDEDMAP, but not one declared in the schema with a particular class? In my db, the linked_class is VMenuOptions. This seems like a possible bug, but maybe there's some subtle difference in the syntax in this case--what do you think?

Comment: You must use "@class":"v"

Comment: Hmmm. No joy. I tried several variants. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Ah yes. So I was able to change my schema to "V" instead of "VMenuOptions" (which subclasses V, by the way) and I was able to get it to work (@Class=V and schema=V). But it still doesn't work, with the exact same syntax, with @Class=VMenuOption and schema=VMenuOption. Any idea why that would be a valid construct?

Comment: PS - I meant "an invalid construct". In other words, if I can only use the base-class V for embedded records, then I can't enforce any property constraints. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: You can use create property yourClass.Options EmbeddedMap VMenuOptions
update #14:0 set Options = {"555":{"@type":"d", "@class":"VMenuOptions","Action":"Test555","Enabled":false},"444":{"@type":"d", "@class":"VMenuOptions","Action":"Test444","Enabled":false}}
update #14:0 put Options = '222', {"@type":"d", "@class":"VMenuOptions","Action":"Test222","Enabled":false}

Comment: Hmmm. I have to step out, but I'll try that later (using direct commands). Creating or updating the property class through the GUI does not work (it appears to work, but the PUT still fails afterward). Maybe a GUI bug?

Comment: Argh! I tried your code and created a second property called TestOptions. It works perfectly. I then compared the schema and there is no difference between how Options and TestOptions are defined. So I tried a PUT into TestOptions (worked) and then into Options (I expected it to fail, because it always has before, but it worked). And now every PUT I try into Options works. I'm not loosing my mind--syntax that did not work before suddenly works now, against the original Options property. I'm using ODB Studio, and did "Refresh Metadata", but is there somewhere else where there might be a cache?